# Xamarin forms tiktok like video scrolling

Tags: .net, xml, xamarin.forms

I trying to create a tiktok like video scrolling with xamarin forms. I have manage to create a data model of video list and the video list with the video is displayed but not in fullscreen.

My problem : **In my xalm code**, i want to display only one video in fullscreen than if a user scoll the next or previous video is also on full screen (like tiktok)

Here is my xalm code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:videoplayer="clr-namespace:Octane.Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer;assembly=Octane.Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer"
    x:Class="lf.MyPages.Lomy.Discover" x:Name="leafDiscoverPage">


    <Grid>

         <CollectionView x:Name="VideosCollectionView"
                        ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
                        RemainingItemsThreshold="1"
                        Scrolled="OnScrolled"
                        RemainingItemsThresholdReached="OnRemainingItemsThresholdReached">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
    <Grid HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference leafDiscoverPage}, Path=Height}"
          WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference leafDiscoverPage}, Path=Width}">
        <!-- Replace 'octane:VideoPlayer' with your actual video player control namespace -->
        <videoplayer:VideoPlayer Source="{Binding UserVideoBlobAdress}"
                            AutoPlay="{Binding IsPlaying}"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        <!-- Add other UI elements as needed -->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

My .cs code :

```
public partial class Discover : ContentPage
    {
        MyUser UserConnected;
        ObservableRangeCollection<UserVideoModel> MyListVideo;
        private int _videoCount = 0;


        public LeafDiscover ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            MyListVideo = new ObservableRangeCollection<UserVideoModel>();

            // Initialize your ListVideo with initial video links
            UserConnected = (MyUser)App.GetProperties("UserConnected");

            OnInitVideoList();

        }

        public void UpdateVideoUrl(List<UserVideoModel> tmpuservideo)
        {
            foreach (var tmpvide in tmpuservideo)
            {
                tmpvide.UserVideoBlobAdress = "https://fo.blob.net/app/"+tmpvide.UserVideoBlobAdress;
            }
        }


        async void OnInitVideoList()
        {
            var MyInitVideo = await VideosManager.GetVideoAsync(UserConnected.MyId.ToString(), false, "");
            UpdateVideoUrl(MyInitVideo);

            foreach (var tmpvide in MyInitVideo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("mook "+ tmpvide.UserVideoBlobAdress);
            }


            MyListVideo.AddRange(MyInitVideo);

            VideosCollectionView.ItemsSource = MyListVideo;


        }

        private void OnRemainingItemsThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_videoCount >= 20)
            {
                // Load more videos or handle the end of the list
                _videoCount = 0;
            }
        }

        private void OnScrolled(object sender, ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs e)
        {
            // Determine the visible item and update playback
            var centerIndex = e.CenterItemIndex;
            UpdateVideoPlayback(centerIndex);
        }

        private void UpdateVideoPlayback(int centerIndex)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < MyListVideo.Count; i++)
            {
                MyListVideo[i].IsPlaying = i == centerIndex;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            // Optionally start playing the first video or the video in the center
            if (MyListVideo.Count > 0)
            {
                MyListVideo[0].PlayVideo(); // or another index if needed
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            // Stop all videos
            foreach (var video in MyListVideo)
            {
                video.StopVideo();
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, [CarouselView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/) is better than CollectionView for your question. Because,

> The CarouselView is a view for presenting data in a scrollable layout, where users can swipe to move through a collection of items.

You could display its items vertically by setting Orientation to [Vertical](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/layout#vertical-layout).

To be full screen, it's easy to set the **VerticalOption** and **HorizontalOption** to Fill or FillAndExpand.

Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: There is not OnRemainingItemsThresholdReached with CarrouselView, do you have an example?

Comment: Do you want to change the ItemsSource at runtime?

Comment: If using a carrousel view,I would to make sure that only the first video is played then when scrolling the next or previous videos start playing. DO you have an example related to my ask please. Thanks for your help

Comment: I add a new answer using CarouselView. You could have a try.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to implement it. How did you link MainPageViewModel to carrouselView?

Comment: In MainPage.cs, set the BindingContext to MainPageViewModel. I update this code at the end of my answer

Comment: thanks you code code, but the performance is low this is why I want to you collectionVIew

Comment: Do you mean it costs much time loading the video?

Comment: May I ask what's the performance difference betweenusing  CarouselView and CollectionView for your case?

Comment: From a online database, I am loading data (Cosmos DB)  in Json format and take the video URL. I do not know why but the video loading work better with collectionView than CarrouselView (no latency, much faster for reading)